# Geometrical structure of the space of all wavefunctions

Tags: differential-geometry, wavefunction, hilbert-space, schroedinger-equation

This is something I cannot grasp. The Schroedinger equation in 1D reads: If $\Psi (x,t) $ is at least differentiable in $t$ and at least two times differentiable in $x$, then

$$\frac{\partial\Psi (x,t)}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{i\hbar} H (x,t) \Psi(x,t) \tag{1}, $$ where $H$ is usually a linear function in $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$, but otherwise can arbitrarily depend on $x$ and $t$. 
I have figured that if $H$ is totally independent of $t$, then the space of a "base solution" of (1) $\Psi (x,t)$ is the trivial fibering of $L^2 (\mathbb{R})$ by the unit circle, with the typical fiber a (class of equivalence of) function(s) in $L^2 (\mathbb{R})$, denote it by $\psi (x)$. But if the Hamiltonian has an arbitrary time-dependence, so that any separation of variables is impossible, then what geometrical structure would one give to the space of all solutions to the general (1)?

Comment: I tend to think of geometric views as unifying: the one you seek would fail at that for the reason I gave.

Comment: Or at least, I would think that the geometrical picture you seek shall account for Schrödinger , Heisenberg, interaction, … pictures.

Comment: The hilbert space itself is  a geometric structure.

Comment: By geometric structure I meant manifold or fiber bundle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be a little surprising, but the space of solutions of the Schrödinger equation has the structure of a classical completely integrable infinite dimensional Hamiltonian system, please see for example the following [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9605191v1) by Marmo and Vilasi.
In order to see that we can cast the Schrödinger equation in the form of Hamilton equations of motion as follows (from the article):

By defining:
$$ q(r, t) = \mathrm{Re} \psi(r, t)$$
$$ p(r, t) = \mathrm{Im} \psi(r, t)$$

The (real and imaginary parts of the) Schrodinger equation can be written as:

$$ \frac{dq}{dt}= \frac{\delta \mathcal{H}}{\delta p}$$ 
$$ \frac{dp}{dt}= -\frac{\delta \mathcal{H}}{\delta q}$$

($\delta$ denotes the functional derivative), with the (classical) Hamiltonian of the system given by:

$$ \mathcal{H}[q, p] := \frac{1}{2\hbar}\int d^3r [\frac{1}{2m}((\nabla q)^2+(\nabla p)^2) + V(r)(q^2+ p^2)]$$

(It is assumed that the quantum Hamiltonian is of the form $H = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\Delta+V(r)$).

Please see,  applications and generalization to nonlinear Schrödinger equations of this formalism in by [Wu, Liu and Niu](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Biao_Wu2/publication/7837648_Geometric_Phase_for_Adiabatic_Evolutions_of_General_Quantum_States/links/00b49531fa8d118f5c000000.pdf) and [Zhang and Wu](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0603073v1).

Two remarks:

1) In the above Hamiltonian system, solutions related by a different global phase are distinct. The classical Hamiltonian is symmetric under a global phase change. In order to obtain the true space of solution we must perform a symplectic reduction of this symmetry.

The resulting phase space is the space of true states (normalized wave functions modulo a global phase). It has the structure of an infinite dimensional complex projective space. This space is endowed with the Fubini-Study metric. The Schrödinger dynamics generate isometries of this space. In addition, according to [Ashtekar and Schilling](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9706069), the geodesic distances between two states provide the measurement probabilities.

2) The quantization of this infinite dimensional Hamiltonian system leads to a  second quantized version of the Schrödinger particles.